# How to add a range of IP addresses in GCP?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I'm trying to add a range of IP addresses as suggested in the Google Cloud Platform:

> Examples: 192.168.0.1, 172.16.0.0/12, 2001:db8::1 or 2001:db8::/64

So I need a range from:

```
123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.99
```

This is what I have tried:

```
123.123.123.0/99
```

But I get:

> Invalid IP address or range. Use CIDR notation and enter the lowest IP address in the subnet.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`123.123.123.0/99` is not the right way to create CIDR block for `123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.99` range

Max value for CIDR block is 32 and you are passing 99.

To cover range of `123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.99` CIDR block will be `123.123.123.0/25`

`123.123.123.0/25` will cover `123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.127`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. This is also available for `123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.199`?

Comment: @LisDya Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing to get more clarity on CIDR

Comment: One more small question please. And to cover `123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.255`?

Comment: @LisDya `123.123.123.0/24` to cover `123.123.123.0 -> 123.123.123.255`. To get CIDR range refer https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: THIS IS SO MISLEADING why google cloud can't make a calculator for this thing? do you guys know something that doesn't require making mental calculations because this is just ridiculous in 2021 having to calculate these IP tables mentally.